# Execute Sql Script is returning "None"

Tags: python, mysql, sql-server, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and while using "Execute SQL Script" keyword i am getting result as None instead data.

versions used - database library - 1.2.4
python 3.6

Tried both keywords Execute SQL Script and Execute SQL String both are returning None.

```
${query_result}=  DB1.Execute SQL Script ./sample_script.sql
```

Also tried using "query" keyword which is returning the data.

```
${query_result}=  DB1.query select * from emp_table;
```

How can i execute sql scripts in Robot Framework?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have at least two spaces between keywords and parameters in Robot Framework as the test syntax is tabular.

```
${query_result}=  DB1.Execute SQL Script ./sample_script.sql
-> ${query_result}=    DB1.Execute SQL Script   ./sample_script.sql

${query_result}=  DB1.query select * from emp_table;
-> ${query_result}=    DB1.query   select * from emp_table;
```

Comment: i have used two spaces between keywords and parameters. My question is "Execute SQL Script" and "Execute SQL String" is not working instead "query" is working with above mentioned versions. Is there a workaround where i can pass .sql script and execute.

Answer (score 0):

The `Execute SQL Script` keyword is used to only execute the SQL statements in the file. It does not return any values. This is typically used to clean up the tables after running some tests(Ex: Run a `DELETE` query).

If you want to run a `SELECT` statement to retrieve data from a DB table you have to use the `Query` keyword.